# Elegant way to set an environment variable in Perl

Tags: perl, environment-variables

In my Perl script, I'm trying to set an environment variable (for example `PATH`). In case it's already defined, add the path to it. Otherwise, set the env. The code:

```
if (defined($ENV{"PATH"})) {
    $ENV{"PATH"} = $ENV{"PATH"}.":/usr/pkgs/";
} else {
    $ENV{"PATH"} = "/usr/pkgs/";
}
```

Is there a better and elegant way to do this in Perl? Maybe a one liner? Note that the env does not have to be `PATH`.

Comment: Are you trying to set an environment variable inside Perl, or outside Perl, in the shell?

Comment: probably `$ENV{PATH} = join(':', grep { defined $_ } ($ENV{PATH}, '/usr/pkgs/'))`;

Comment: @TLP Inside perl script (the env might be already defined in the shell that runs the script).

Comment: `defined` handles an unset PATH, but not an empty path. You'd want to replace `defined` with `length` to handle both.

Comment: @ikegami Or just use `$_` itself.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the [Env](https://perldoc.perl.org/Env) Core module:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Env qw(@PATH);

push @PATH, '/usr/pkgs/';
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd probably write something like this, where I use the length to determine what to add on (although I don't expect "0" to ever be the value of `$ENV{PATH}`). The `Config` module knows what the path separator should be:

```
use Config qw(%Config);

$ENV{PATH} .= ( length $ENV{PATH} ? $Config{path_sep} : '' ) . "/usr/pkgs/";
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on [Mathias'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5672245/mathias-weidner) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67164281/725418), which basically uses `split` as a hack to create an empty list for empty values in `$ENV{PATH}`. You can use the simpler check `||` which checks if the value in the variable is false, which in a Perl scalar means basically empty string, undefined or zero. Since we want to avoid the possibility of adding a colon to the start of the string, we want to replace it with the empty list `()`. So it becomes:

```
$ENV{PATH} = join ":", $ENV{PATH} || (), "/usr/pkgs/";
```

Technically, `0` could be a valid path, but it feels unlikely to be a correct path.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `split` and `join` like this:

```
$ENV{PATH} = join(":", split(/:/, $ENV{PATH}), "/usr/pkgs")
```

Comment: `PATH= /usr/bin/perl -e 'print join(":",$ENV{PATH},"/abc"),"\n"'` prints `:/abc`

Comment: @TLP, Maybe not in this particular case, but it's generally required to handle an initially empty/unset var. This solution is what I'd use too (though bdf's solution is more efficient).

Comment: FWIW, I'd be surprised if there was any noticeable performance gap between mine and this one. You'd have to have a huge PATH and a really, really fast program for this to be a problem. :)

Comment: Ok, I see, `split` is used as a hack to filter out empty string. You could just do `$ENV{PATH} || ()`, which would not even give a warning for uninitialized value, but still filter out empty or false values.

Comment: @ikegami Isn't it a bug, though, that `split /:/, ""` returns `()` and not `""`?